# IIS 8 with PHP 5.6: WinCache VS Zend Op Cache

Tags: php, iis, opcache

[Zend Op Cache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php) is compiled by default on PHP5.5+, but 
[IIS encourages use of WinCache](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/use-the-windows-cache-extension-for-php) for opcode caching.

what is the extension that will give me the best performance and stability on IIS?

there are benchmarks, case studies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That article about WinCache is over seven years old, and is only about PHP 5.2.x and 5.3.x, which did not come with a built-in OpCache that worked on Windows.  Now that PHP comes with its own OpCache, you should be using that one.

Additionally, the official release notes for WinCache version 1.3.5.0, the first version to support PHP 5.5, say:

> Opcode Cache is disabled by default for PHP 5.5 because Opcache is available in Core

This is a clear indication that the developers of WinCache agree.

---

**NOTE:** You can still use WinCache for its *userspace* caching functions. This question is only about the *OpCache* component of WinCache.

Comment: Do you have any reasons why OpCache is preferable over WinCache? WinCache is still being actively developed, i.e. there are WinCache releases for PHP 7.1 (the just released version of PHP is 7.1.3).

Comment: @icc97 I have updated the answer. *Also*, while it is true that there are *now* releases for the PHP 7.1, development has been pretty spotty in the past. For example, PHP 5.6 was release in August 2014, but a *stable* release of WinCache supporting it did not come out until March 2015 (though a beta did come out in July 2014, most people would not want to install a beta on a production server).